# Check if Oracle Resource Management is enabled

Tags: database, oracle

What's the SQL statement I have to run as SYS to find out whether my DB uses Resource management or not?

Answer (score 0):

Resource management is enabled by default. 
You must know if your user is using resource manager OR not.

Find out list of users/roles which are consumer of resources manager groups by executing: 
As sys:
select * from DBA_RSRC_CONSUMER_GROUP_PRIVS ;

For a logged in user, find out any resource groups assigned to itself by :
select * from USER_RSRC_CONSUMER_GROUP_PRIVS ;

- Abhi